# Dropping a column with an invisible constraint

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, constraints

I've read through a lot of posts on this but nothing has worked.

I'm trying to add a default value to a column like this:

```
        AlterColumn("dbo.BusinessUnit_Map", "RelationshipType", c => c.String(nullable: false, defaultValue: "RollsUpTo"));
```

This produces the error:

> The object 'DF_dbo.BusinessUnit_Map_RelationshipType' is dependent on column 'RelationshipType'.
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN RelationshipType failed because one or more objects access this column.

I cannot find this constraint anywhere. Below is a screenshot showing the only default constraint on the table.

[image]

One interesting thing is, if I try dropping the column and re-adding it, that works fine. It's only when I use `AlterColumn` that it fails.

I've tried dropping the constraints like this:

```
            Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.BusinessUnit_Map DROP CONSTRAINT DF_dbo.BusinessUnit_Map_RelationshipType");
```

But the `.` is a syntax error, so I replace it with three underscores:

```
            Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.BusinessUnit_Map DROP CONSTRAINT DF_dbo___BusinessUnit_Map_RelationshipType");
```

But the system responds with

> 'DF_dbo___BusinessUnit_Map_RelationshipType' is not a constraint.
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Where is this constraint and how can I turn it off?

**Update**

One suggestion is to try this query to search for that constraint:

```
select o.type_desc,o2.name as parent_name,*  from sys.objects as o
left join sys.objects as o2 on o.parent_object_id=o2.object_id
where o.name='DF_dbo.BusinessUnit_Map_RelationshipType'
```

This returned zero results, so I modified it to see what it would tell me about `BusinessUnit_Map`

```
select o.type_desc,o2.name as parent_name,*  from sys.objects as o
left join sys.objects as o2 on o.parent_object_id=o2.object_id
where o2.name='BusinessUnit_Map'
```

The results of this query are shown below, and they do not contain the mystery constraint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

With this command you'll find the object to the name:

```
select o.type_desc,o2.name as parent_name,*  from sys.objects as o
left join sys.objects as o2 on o.parent_object_id=o2.object_id
where o.name='DF_dbo.BusinessUnit_Map_RelationshipType'
```

Look at the column "type_desc" if it is really a default constraint. The column "parent_name" should tell you the name of the table this is bound to.

Hope you'll find your "invisible constraint" :-)

-- old Text

Try it with square brackets. Dots, spaces and other "breaking" keys are not allowed within a name normally:

```
Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.BusinessUnit_Map DROP CONSTRAINT [DF_dbo.BusinessUnit_Map_RelationshipType]");
```

Comment: @Samo, edited my answer... You'll find a statement there which will bring you details for the object with the name 'DF_dbo.BusinessUnit_Map_RelationshipType'

Comment: I modified your query to look for all the constraints on `BusinessUnitMap` and DF_dbo___BusinessUnit_Map_IDGUID is the only default constraint that showed up :(

Comment: @Samo, did you get any other information, what kind of object this is. The leading DF points to a default constraint, but it could be anything else too... What other information can you get from your query? Please post its result (edit your question).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89961/discussion-between-samo-and-shnugo).